# Can I block a seller on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

I just wanted to find the cheapest mattress on `amazon.de`. To do so, I chose the category `matress` and adjusted the filter to `90x200` (the size). Then I got this:

[image: Search result]

pages after pages with the same product, just minor variations, from a seller called "MetaTex".

Is there any way I can block a seller to get relevant search results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try including `-metatex` in your search terms.

Comment: Amazon's search algorithm doesn't work like that sadly. I was searching for laptops and this sleazy seller marked their product as having every processor type and as every type of laptop (even though it was a laptop accessory). I tried to remove them by typing -L1B, -"L1B" and even -"LB1 High Performance". Didn't filter them out of my results WITHOUT filtering my search for a laptop out of my results (showing me crayons, for example).